# Moshi Json / Kotlin - Empty String to Null (for numerical properties)

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have a model class containing Long and Int properties and I am using Moshi Library to parse a json string into this class.

```
data class Adjust (
    var appId: String?,
    var clicks: Long?,
    var count: Int?)
```

If I parse a json like this `{"appId":"1", "clicks":""}`, I get an error `Expected a long but was  at path $.clicks`

Same thing happens for the `Int` field.

What can I do short of adding two custom adapters so that the blank strings are parsed as null and do not error out?

The custom adapter I wrote is like this:

```
object EmptyStringToNullAdapter {
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(string: String) = string.toLongOrNull()

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: Long) = value.toString()
}
```

This works but I have to write another similar one for Int and maybe in future if other numerical fields are added, more such adapters! What is the better approach here?

Comment: If you have the option to communicate with someone who created the API, tell them to send a null instead of an empty String, because that's what it is. It's a String.

Comment: Short of changing your server, I think your adapters are the best way to go. Just add one for Int, Long, and Double, and you're good.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Wouldn't that be easy :) But you know they're called `end users` for a reason!
@EricCochran - That's the way I am going for now. I tried so many things like adding generics, or a AdapterFactory, but I figured they're more complicated than this situation calls for, perhaps.